# Converting VBA to VBS

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to convert the below VBA code to VBS script. This code takes a screenshot of the present screen and saves it in an existing document. When I try I am getting the below:

```
   <'800a0401' expected end of statement> error window.
```

.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0

SendKeys "%{PRTSC}", True

Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\johnsmith\Documents\Test.doc"

With objWord
    .Visible = True
    .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    .Selection.Paste
    .ActiveDocument.Save   
End With
objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot have API declarations, strongly typed variables, or constants coming from type libraries (e.g. `wdWindowStateMaximize`) in VBS. Not sure why you have the API in the first place though because you then duplicate it with SendKeys.

Comment: @GSerg you **can** use constants coming from **any** source if you declare them explicitly, e.g. `Const wdWindowStateMaximize = 1`. On the other hand, _VBScript_ lacks [(among others) Clipboard Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/30593abb(v=vs.84).aspx) so hard to perform e.g.  `.Selection.Paste`.

Comment: @JosefZ Constans declared in the script itself are not coming from anywhere - they are declared in-place. Constans declared in a type library that I'm talking about cannot be used. `.Selection.Paste` will certainly work because it belongs to Excel type library and is not related to VB6's `Clipboard`.

Comment: @GSerg You can use constants from type libraries when you reference them in the script host. Classic ASP has that ability and Windows script jobs (*.wsf) [can do it, too](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/01/12/how-can-i-access-a-type-library-from-within-a-script.aspx). So if you don't want to declare every constant manually, you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good mixed **[Batch/VB.Net]** to take a screenshot, so i share it with you, may be helps you !

```
/*
@echo off & cls
title DBatchprintscreen
::Autor Delmar Grande
::fórum DBatchScript  [url]www.dbatchscript.forumeiros.com/]http://dbatchscript.forumeiros.com/[/url]
::forum Bbat.forumeiro.com [url]www.Bbat.forumeiro.com[/url]
::Data  Qui 11 Jul 2013
echo Chargement...
findstr "'%skip%VB" "%~f0" > "%tmp%\%~n0.vb"
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /S ^"%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vbc.exe^"') do set vbc=%%i
if /i "%vbc%"=="" cls & color 1c & echo Ce script a besoin du framework & pause
cls
:7
%vbc% /nologo /out:"%tmp%\%~n0.exe" "%tmp%\%~n0.vb"
"%tmp%\%~n0.exe"
pause
del "%tmp%\%~n0.vb" >NUL 2>&1
del "%tmp%\%~n0.exe" >NUL 2>&1
exit
*/
Imports System.Windows.Forms 'VB
Module ModulePrintscreen 'VB
    Sub Main() 'VB
        Dim MaDate As String 'VB
        SendKeys.SendWait("{%}({PRTSC})") 'VB
        If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then 'VB
            MaDate = Format(Now,"dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") 'VB
            My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage.Save(MaDate & ".jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 'VB
        End If 'VB
    End Sub 'VB
End Module 'VB
```